# Excel files and C++

Tags: c++, excel

How i can read\export data within a C++ application to Excel files? I was found the xlslib project, but it only compiles with MingW on Windows. My target platform is windows (MVS2008)

Comment: Which OS do you want to target? And which compiler?

Comment: why not use simple CSV(Comma Separated Values)?

Comment: Unfortunately, manipulating Excel documents in C++ is not quite as easy as using the Microsoft.Office.Excel.Interop classes in .NET. In .NET, it's almost the same as coding in Excel itself. Native C++, from what I can tell, requires COM programming to access it and from the looks of it, it ain't pretty.

Comment: I need of formatting, thus i'm not using CSV

Comment: Will Excel be installed on the machines the application will be used on?

Comment: have you tried http://npoi.codeplex.com/ ?

Comment: yes, will Excel be installed on the target machines

Comment: I'm developing a pure C++ win32 application, without .Net platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're stuck with unmanaged C++ and need to communicate directly with Excel you'll need the COM automation interfaces. See the MSDN article [link text](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196776)

If you want the expressive power of the new managed interop, I think you may need to wrap your C++ code in an interop dll.

Comment: Here is another link that has sample code: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/216686#/en-us/kb/216686

Answer (score 2):

You can try this commercial library http://www.libxl.com, it works with Visual Studio 2008 and doesn't require Microsoft Excel.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, you can also give a try to ExcelFormat lib.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42504/ExcelFormat-Library

It doesn't require Excel installed, and it's very easy to use.