# Extract data from excel file using C++

Tags: c++, excel, input

Can anyone provide me a direct and easy way (ofcourse with codes and other necessary libraries to be included for right execution) to input data from excel file to C++? Actually, I need to input a huge amount of data to input from excel in C++ and finally when computed with C++, linking outputs with excel again. Can anyone help please?

Comment: "ofcourse with codes and other necessary libraries to be included for right execution" - > if you pay us of course ;-)

Answer (score 7):

As others have mentioned, using [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) files is the easiest route, as they can be imported/exported to and from Excel.  This would likely be the most effective solution because it would require nothing more than the standard C++ libraries and would likely be much faster than using an Excel library.  Once you have the CSV file, you can open it in Excel and convert it to a "real" Excel file if you wish.

If you are dealing with `.xlsx` files, you can take advantage of the fact that these files are simply [zipped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) collections of [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) files.  More information can be found [at this website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205.aspx).  You would just have to find a zipping library and an XML library.

Otherwise, there are a few Excel libraries available, such as [LibXL](http://www.libxl.com/) or [xlsLib](http://xlslib.sourceforge.net/).

Finally, there are several posts on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) about this very topic.  See the following:

[C++ library to load Excel (.xls) files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876720/c-library-to-load-excel-xls-files)

[Excel files and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218535/excel-files-and-c)

[What is a simple and reliable C library for working with Excel files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493111/what-is-a-simple-and-reliable-c-library-for-working-with-excel-files)

Comment: So can you quickly show me how to convert xlsx file into csv file by using codes then convert it back to xlsx? I need to modify xlsx file downloaded from a website for modification.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to export data from Excel as CSV and write back to CSV.

Answer (score 1):

Check out these pages on [Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216686) [Automation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196776).

Answer (score 0):

For native .xls file OLE XLS from SM Software does a decent job... nothing for free though!