# C++/MFC - How to export window contents to Excel?

Tags: c++, excel, csv, export

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excel files and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218535/excel-files-and-c)

I am using an API called UltimateGrid which allows me to easily create Excel-like grids using C++/MFC. I need a way to export all of the contents of these grids to an actual Excel document. I could not find anything about this in the documentation for this API. Then I got to thinking ... exporting contents to an Excel document is a common requirement in applications. I was thinking about creating a right-click menu option for exporting a grid to Excel. I feel like I am reinventing the wheel as I start to code this. I googled around and saw a lot of common ways of dealing with this when database tables are involved. But that is not the case here. My underlying "datasource" is not a database table, but rather just some business objects internal to the application. Am I going to have to just write my own custom handler that iterates through the business objects corresponding to the rows and output them to a CSV file to be used by Excel?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how automated you want this to be.  I did this a while back (as in years ago), so forgive me if this info is out of date.  Here's what I remember:

1. CSV is fine, as long as you don't want to export formats, graphs, etc...
2. You should be able to access the Excel object from your C++ code, and Microsoft should have documentation on how to do this.
3. It may be easier to have your C++ generate a VBScript to access the component, since last I checked, there was much less red tape to doing it that way, but you could run into permissions/security issues with this method.

Also, have you checked to see if UltimateGrid supports other export formats that are compatible with Excel?

Answer (score 0):

If there are no other options, I think you might want to look into DDE (Dynamic Data Exchange). 
There could be a limitation on that OS should be Microsoft Windows, however you might be able to find some open source/runtime that supports other OSs as well.

One that I used long ago was NDde.